# mysql error 1136 'column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Tags: mysql

I've tried to add a new column called "bidUpIncrement2" into "HotelMetrics.reporte 06-05" table in MySQL buy i can't. 
This is what i wanna try:

INSERT INTO HotelMetrics.`reporte 06-05` (bidUpIncrement2)
VALUES ('0,05',
'0,05',
'0,05')

I've already create the column with Alter Table (data type float(19,2)).

The error that appears is "Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". 
I wolud thanks any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a correct syntax for multiple inserts on a single command and it should be as

```
INSERT INTO `HotelMetrics`.`reporte 06-05` (bidUpIncrement2) 
VALUES 
('0,05'),
('0,05'), 
('0,05') ;
```

Comment: It isn't the problem. I've already check that. I don't know why this error keeps